# On Mac OS X how can I log to Console.app from the terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, console

I've seen the use of `/dev/console` in several scripts for Mac OSX but I'm not sure how it's being used. I checked Console.app and didn't see the results of my test command:

```
echo test > /dev/console
```

being printed out there, so where does it go to, or how would you use it?

Comment: @Qosmo. This question is 100% valid for Super User and there is no need or reason to migrate it.

Comment: Being valid doesn't imply it would be better served there? Why was it created? Anyway it's just a suggestion...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/dev/console` device is not especially related to the *Console* application.

In Mac OS X 10.6, the *Console* application has two kinds of data sources that it reads: normal log files (e.g. the files in `/var/log/`), and messages logged through the (Apple extended) syslog facility.

If you have a log file that you want to monitor, you can use the *File* > *Open…* menu item (⌘O) to view the file in *Console*.
Note: The only way to remove a file from *Console*’s list of files seems to be to use its *File* > *Move to Trash* menu item (⌘⌫); be prepared to pull the file out of the Trash if you just want to stop watching it in *Console*.

You can use the [*syslog*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/syslog.1.html) command-line program to send messages to the syslog facility.

```
syslog -s Your message goes here. \(quote special chars for the shell'!)'
```

However, under the default configuration, this message will never show up in any of the *Console* views because it’s “level” is too low to be important. This initial filtering is due by [*syslogd*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/syslogd.8.html). It is configured by the [`asl.conf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/asl.conf.5.html) and [`syslog.conf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/syslog.conf.5.html) files. The default configuration does not store most messages if their Level is too low (and `syslog -s` defaults to the lowest level). *Console* can only show message that have been stored by *syslogd*.

You can change the value of the Level field by using the `-l` option:

```
syslog -s -l notice This message should show up in \"All Messages\" \
  with a Facility of syslog.
```

The `notice` level is the (default) lowest level for which *syslogd* will store most messages.

A message generated like this will show up in *Console*’s built-in “All Messsages” database search
(the file `All Messages.aslquery` in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/ASLQueries/` technically limits it to message where the Facility field “contains” the empty string, but this condition is trivially satisfied by any Facility value).

If you want your message to appear in *Console*’s built-in “Console Messages” database search, then you must be a bit more specific. It only shows (stored) messages that have a Facility field that equals `com.apple.console` (see the file `Console Messages.aslquery` in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/ASLQueries/`). You can generate such messages with *syslog* by the `-k` option to set the Facility field.

```
syslog -s -k Facility com.apple.console \
          -k Level notice \
          -k Message 'This will show up in "Console Messages"'
```

When using `-k`, all the options and the message itself must be specified with sets of `-k key value` arguments (we can not use `-l` to set the level). This means that we have to put the message a single argument so it can be the value of the Message field.

Comment: So what is the "logger" command used for? Is it part of syslog?

Comment: @cwd: It also uses the syslog facility. Apple’s syslog has two main interfaces: [*syslog(3)*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html), and [*asl(3)*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html). The former is fairly standard on most Unix-y systems these days; *logger* uses it. The latter is an Apple-specific extension; the *syslog* command uses it. *Console* sees messages from both, but the “Console Messages” search needs an Apple-extended Facility value (which *logger* can not make).

Answer (score 9):

i use:

`logger Hello World`

always works for me. dumps "hello world" to syslog, which should show up in console.app

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but it may be the device called when >console is entered in the username field of the login window. When you enter the above it dumps you the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a file of your choosing that you could then view in the Console application.

If you want logging for user level use:

```
echo "test" > /Users/$USER/Library/Logs/your_script.log
```

or for something that is loaded for all users:

```
echo "test" > /Library/Logs/your_script.log
```